# Single Currency Org, How to display (AUD) next to currency field on Opp object?

Tags: sales-cloud, ui, currency, workspaceapi

I'm an Admin on a single currency org, set to Australia (AUD). Client would like the currency to display next to the currency field. Apart from enabling multi, is there another way to be able to display AUD next to the currency field on the Opportunity obj in records to users? Essentially like this: Amount $400,000.00 (AUD) or something similar. Any help appreciated.

Comment: A formula field. It won't be exactly "next" to it but it might be good enough.

Comment: You can use formula field and the return should be text. try this formula Text(Amount) &"(AUD)"

Answer (score 0):

I think displaying the currency symbol alongside the currency value in a single currency org without enabling multi-currency can be accomplished through a few methods.

**Formula**

- Create a new formula field on the Opportunity object with a return type of Text.
  Use a formula similar to the following:
  TEXT(Amount) & " (AUD)"
- This will display the Amount value followed by " (AUD)".
- Place this formula field next to the Amount field on the page layout or use it in reports as needed.

**Field-Level Help Text**

- Although not directly adding "(AUD)" to the display, a simple method is to use the help text feature of the Amount field. You can add a note indicating that all amounts are in AUD. When users hover over the info icon next to the field, they'll see the note.

Hope this helps!